# Como crearían un algoritmo para generar pines Numéricos

Tags: php, algoritmos

Buen día ,

Quiero saber si existe un algoritmo/librería o si alguien tiene experiencia generando pines que no sean consecutivos, donde le paso una cantidad y me devuelve un arreglo con los pines, hay una particularidad y es que la funcionalidad se puede ejecutar cada mes y en cada generación los pines no se debe repetir (Por lo cual es posible que deba hacer uso de BD) . El tamaño del pin es de  11 dígitos. y el objetivo es garantizar algún grado de complejidad para que no se adivinar tan fácilmente. El lenguaje de programación en el que se esta trabajando es PHP pero si se conoce en otro lenguaje se puede manejar como servicio. Agradezco cualquier orientación

Ejemplo 
 75132165417
 85532465417
 ...

```
/**
** Funcionalidad Generar Pines
** @param INT cantidad : Cantidad de pines a generar
** @return Array arreglo con los pines generados
**/ 

  Private Array generar_pines(Int cantidad){
    //Genere pines aleatorio que no se repitan
   //Tener en cuenta si ya se genero en fechas anteriores
   $cantidad = 5;
   $arrayPines = array();
   $cantidadGenerados = 0;
   $min = 9000000000;
   $max = 9000000100;

  //CodigoGenerarPines
   while ($cantidad >= $cantidadGenerados){ 

     // En caso de querer concatenar con fecha y mes usar 
     $year = str_split(date("y"));
     $month = str_split(date("m"));

      //$pin =  mt_rand($min,$max);

    $pinPropuesto = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($pinPropuesto);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $cantidad; $i++) {

   /**
   * Comparar Pin generado con pines almacenados en BD.
   * Actualmente se almacena en MySql 
   * Por temas de desempeño contemplar Base de Datos NoSql (Redis)
   * Ya sea para un cache o para el almacenamiento de los pines
   * Si existePin devuelve True Existe el pin, False no existe
   **/
       if(!$this->existePin($pin)){
           $arrayPines = $pinPropuesto[$i] ;
           echo $pinPropuesto[$i]."<br>";
           $cantidadGenerados++;
       }

    }


   }
    return Array


 }
```

Comment: Has intentado hacer algo? pon algo de código para que podamos guiarnos.

Comment: Inicialmente probé la funcion  mt_rand, y genere pines y lo almacene en una base de datos, pense en concatenarlos con fecha para garantizar que quedaran diferentes en cada generación, pero tuve los siguientes inconvenientes el tamaño del pin debia ser entre 10 y 12 , si le agregaba una fecha me ocupaba gran parte del pin, y segundo los pines generados podian ser 50mil , 100mil, esto hacia un poco más complicado manejar los repetidos.

Comment: ¿cada cuanto se genera un pin? ¿cada mes uno? creo que no he entendido bien esa parte.

Comment: Cada mes  o 3 meses se puede generar  un paquete de 50mil pines

Comment: La pregunta es buena, pero editala, agrega un poco de lo que haz intentado, porque veo que puede ser cerrada ya que no muestras un poco de investigación o trabajo por tu parte

Comment: @Jorius agrego algo de lo que he realizado que no ha cumplido lo que quiero. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Con esta función puedes generar id o pines aleatorios.

```
           function generarCodigo($longitud) { 
           $key = '';
           $pattern = '1234567890';
           $max = strlen($pattern)-1;

           for($i=0;$i < $longitud;$i++) $key .= $pattern{mt_rand(0,$max)};
           return $key;
           }

         //Ejemplo de uso
         $canidad = 50;
         for($c=0; $c<=$canidad; $c++){
         echo generarCodigo(11)."<br/>";
         }
```

solo pasa la cantidad de dígitos a generar y las veces que quieres que se repita, el código mostrara pines aleatorios con lo que contiene en la cadena $pattern, si quieres agregar más seguridad a la generación de pines, puedes agregar más caracteres a la cadena ej. Letras (abcd, ABCD) o simbolos ($#/) etc.

Comment: Esta parte me es útil para mejorar la parte de la generación del Pin, quedan unos problemas por resolver que seria evitar los repetidos,y ahí es donde esta mi mayor problema pues cuando genero un paquete de 50 mil pines , cada uno de estos aleatorios tendría que validarse contra la base de datos, si los 50 mil nuevos son iguales a los que ya he generado en otra fecha eso significa 50mil consultas en la bd que me retornarían falso hasta que logre encontrar los que no se repitan. no se si estoy enfocando mal la solución.